# HP Notebook - dmesg suggests to use hid-rmi driver 'psmouse.synaptics_touchpad=1' instead of old driver - rmi driver not working

Tags: gnome-shell, input-devices, wayland, libinput, hp-touchpad

I was checking through dmesg and saw that there is a suggestion to use the newer hid-rmi driver for touchpad for my laptop which is new.(Model: HP-15-BS576TX).

From dmesg:

```
[    2.507282] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5648], y [..4826]
[    2.538726] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1292..], y [1026..]
[    2.538729] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: SYN3251 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
[    2.601437] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.2, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xf00123/0x840300/0x2e800/0x400000, board id: 3320, fw id: 2548310
[    2.641628] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
```

So, I booted with kernel boot parameter "psmouse.synaptics_touchpad=1". But, there seems to be little change and the touchpad continues using the old driver:

**:~$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input102
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=1
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 30000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003
```

The dmesg with the kernel parameter psmouse.synaptics_touchpad=1 has not much information, except that touchpad continues using the old driver:

```
  psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5648], y [..4826]
 [    2.322704] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1292..], y [1026..]
 [    2.322707] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Trying to set up SMBus access
 [    2.325589] psmouse serio1: synaptics: SMbus companion is not ready yet
 [    2.372028] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
 [    2.388206] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.2, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xf00123/0x840300/0x2e800/0x400000, board id: 3320, fw id: 2548310
 [    2.428811] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
```

The i2c-hid, hid-rmi modules are available with the kernel - 4.13.0-19-generic

Any chance of getting this touchpad/trackpad to work with the newer hid-rmi driver? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This driver (i2c_i801) is blacklisted in ubuntu. See /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. You can try to comment out the line that says: `blacklist i2c_i801`,
but you may experience suspend issues. If your touchpad freezes after resuming from suspend, try adding rules for unloading (rmmod) the module pre-suspend and reloading it (modprobe) post-resume. See: `man systemd-sleep`. Good luck! :)

Comment: I tried enabling i2c_i801 and it seems have no effect. Same device node is created and in dmesg, found a line "[   11.683201] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SMBus using PCI interrupt". I think this is not the driver? i2c_i801 is left unused.

Comment: You should use the kernel parameter as well.

Comment: Yes. I used psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=1 with kernel 4.18. Removed i2c_i801 from blacklist.conf. updated grub2 and booted. It seems the modules like i2c-hid, hid-rmi etc are not loaded. i2c_i801, rmi_smbus shows it's not used when probed with lsmod command. But, I'm not sure if the new bus is used, Please check, if it is working - https://paste.ee/p/9v3vw